# How to access JSON elements in python swiftly and efficiently?

Tags: python, json

I am calling an API provided by Steam to get user details. I am using Python's requests and JSON library to call this. My code:

```
import requests 
import json
response = requests.get("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&steamids=76561198330357188")

data = response.json()

print(data['response'])
```

The output comes:

```
{'players': [{'steamid': '76561198330357188', 'communityvisibilitystate': 3, 'profilestate': 1, 'personaname': 'saditstar', 'profileurl': 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/saditrahman/', 'avatar': 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f8/f8d41f4064e1df34b1b5c439e775e222fb171ed3.jpg', 'avatarmedium': 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f8/f8d41f4064e1df34b1b5c439e775e222fb171ed3_medium.jpg', 'avatarfull': 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f8/f8d41f4064e1df34b1b5c439e775e222fb171ed3_full.jpg', 'avatarhash': 'f8d41f4064e1df34b1b5c439e775e222fb171ed3', 'lastlogoff': 1628598684, 'personastate': 1, 'realname': 'Kowsar Rahman Sadit', 'primaryclanid': '103582791429521408', 'timecreated': 1473564722, 'personastateflags': 0, 'loccountrycode': 'BD'}]}
```

My simple question is how can I access elements such as `profilestate` or like `personaname`?

Comment: How do you normally access attributes of these nested structures?

Comment: I am actually new to this segment. Searched all over the internet but couldn't find. I am assuming with a for loop.

Comment: I suggest looking into the [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function.

Comment: @bicarlsen: The `json` lib is not needed here. The OP has shown that `data['response']` already produces a `dict`.

Comment: Hmm... `Searched all over the internet`? (a) that's not possible, (b) what were your search terms?

Comment: @quamrana I simply meant to look at examples of that for how to use the returned object. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well when I say I searched over the internet, of course I don't mean I have searched the entire internet.

Comment: Anyway, I got my answer below and thanks for the information.

Comment: If that's your answer, then you need to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access these values like the following sample.

```
>>> vals = {'players': [{'steamid': '76561198330357188', 'communityvisibilitystate': 3, 'profilestate': 1, 'personaname': 'saditstar', 'profileurl': 'https://steamcommunity.com/id/saditrahman/', 'avatar': 'http                                                                                                                                                                                                             8d41f4064e1df34b1b5c439e775e222fb171ed3_medium.jpg', 'avatarfull': 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f8/f8d41f4064e1df34b1b5c439e775e222fb171ed3_full.jpg', 'avatarhash': 'f8d41f4064e1df34b1b5c439e775e222fb171ed3', 'lastlogoff': 1628598684, 'personastate': 1, 'realname': 'Kowsar Rahman Sadit', 'primaryclanid': '103582791429521408', 'timecreated': 1473564722, 'personastateflags': 0, 'loccountrycode': 'BD'}]}
>>> [item.get('profilestate') for item in vals['players'] ]
[1]
```